# Python Selenium - How to handle alert that jQuery create using ready event?

Tags: python, jquery, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If the html structure of the website I want to parse is like this,
'''

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ex02</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">`enter code here`
         jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            alert(jQuery('p').text());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The Dom is ready!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

I can't handle alert and everything because of "ready event".

**"driver.switch_to.alert.accept()"** and
**"actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)   actions.perform()"** are useless.

what do i do??? please help

oh i use chromewebdriver

Comment: what happened when you did "driver.switch_to.alert.accept()"? Nothing?

Comment: my program fall into infinite loop while i clicked alert using mouse

Comment: What if you don't interact with the mouse.